# Adding Bootstrap Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.4 to Laravel 5.3 project locally

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, phpstorm

I'm new to Laravel and Bootstrap. I know I can easily add the Bootstrap CDN link like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"...>`

But I would like to know how I can add Bootstrap "**locally**" after downloading the `.zip` file of *Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.4* which I downloaded from Bootstrap [website](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/)

I unzip the zipped file and i got these files.

```
[parent directory]
dist/
docs/
grunt/
js/
nuget/
scss/
_config.yml
.editorconfig
.gitattributes
.gitignore
.hound.yml
.travis.yml
bower.json
CHANGELOG.md
CNAME
composer.json
CONTRIBUTING.md
Gemfile
Gemfile.lock
Gruntfile.js
ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md
LICENSE
package.js
package.json
README.md
sache.json
```

I want to know how I can add it to my Laravel Project on PHPStorm. I'm using Laravel 5.3

Currently, the files in my `public` folder are what's shown in the image below.

[image]

Where should I paste the contents of the zip file? (for `font-awesome` I used the `css` and `js` folder to store `font-awesome`'s contents)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the file in `public` and use this in blade view:

```
<link href="{{ asset('path/from/public/to/file.css') }}">
```

In your case, if you open the `dist` directory from bootstrap you can find `js` and `css`, copy each file in the destination folder, for example in `public/css/bootstrap.css` and then call it in blade with:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}">
```

Notice that I do not set `public` in the url

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found it under dist folder and I can now work offline without worrying that cache might be deleted.